# How do I treat a special string as an array and select the second object from it in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column in my table which has values like this

```
1923195445602;182343;en
```

or

```
1830310365602;175824;en;EVENT
```

Data is split by ";"

I want to select the second value of it. My thought is to find a way to treat this string as an array. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `select split_part(colname,';',2);`